# order of $aHa^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone please tell me if this proof is correct?

Question:  If $H$ be a finite subgroup of $G$ and $a\in G$, let $aHa^{-1}=\{aha^{-1}|h\in H\}$. What is the order(or cardinality) of $aHa^{-1}?$.

Here is my attempt:

Lemma: $aHa^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Proof: Every element of $aHa^{-1}$ is in $G$, so $aHa^{-1}\subset G$.

For $h_1,h_2\in H$, $(ah_1a^{-1})(ah_2a^{-1})=ah_1h_2a^{-1}=aha^{-1}$ as $h_1.h_2=h\in H$ for some $h\in H$ because $H$ is a subgroup of G.
$(aha^{-1})(ah^{-1}a^{-1})=e$ where $E$ is the identity  element of $H,G$ and $aHa^{-1}$.Thus $aHa^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
$\blacksquare$

Let the order of $aHa^{-1}$ be denoted by $o(aHa^{-1})$. Clearly, $o(aHa^{-1})=o(Ha^{-1})$.We know that tthe cardinality of the right cosets of $H$ is $o(H)$.So, $o(aHa^{-1})=o(H)$

Please comment if my proof is correct.

Comment: Where do you ever use the lemma that $aHa^{-1}$ is a subgroup?  Why not just start at the last paragraph "Let the order of..."?

Comment: Perhaps there was no need to do that but I was thinking of order as in order of a group,hence the trouble.

Comment: True that seems reasonable but I noticed you refer to $o(Ha^{-1})$ even $Ha^{-1}$ is not a group.  If it's obvious to you (as in you can see how to prove it) that $|aHa^{-1}| = |Ha^{-1}|$ then it's equally obvious that $|Ha^{-1}|=|H|$.

Comment: You are right.As I said, that bit was unnecessary.

Comment: @ErickWong In the last part why is $o(aHa^{-1}) = o(Ha^{-1})$

Comment: @K.Dutta Why are you asking me? I didn't write the proof.  Anyway, just find a bijection between the sets $aHa^{-1}$ and $Ha^{-1}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to avoid using the word "clearly", even though your statement is correct. Why is it true that $|aHa^{-1}|=|Ha^{-1}|$? A better way to show this is to build a map $\phi \colon H \to aHa^{-1}$ given by $\phi(h)= aha^{-1}$. This is surjective, since any $aha^{-1} \in aHa^{-1}$ is mapped to by $\phi(h)$. It is injective, since $ah_1a^{-1}=ah_2a^{-1}$ implies $h_1=h_2$ by cancellation. Thus $\phi$ is a bijection and the two subgroups have the same order.

Comment: I do not yet have the reputation to vote this up.

Comment: No worries, thanks for accepting!

Comment: Since the set H is finite proving the map injective should be sufficient in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Looks correct. However, you can prove this more easily by noting that 
$$aha^{-1}=aga^{-1}\implies a^{-1}(aha^{-1})a=a^{-1}(aga^{-1})a\implies h=g$$

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 4(b) on p.47.
I solved this problem as follows:

> Let $\phi$ be a mapping such that $\phi:H\ni b\mapsto aba^{-1}\in aHa^{-1}$.
> If $\phi(c)=\phi(d)$, then $c=a^{-1}\phi(c)a=a^{-1}\phi(d)a=d$.
> So, $\phi$ is injective.
> If $c\in aHa^{-1}$, then we can write $c=aha^{-1}=\phi(h)$ for some $h\in H$.
> So, $\phi$ is surjective.
> So, $o(H)=o(aHa^{-1})$.